# How to use the numericRefinementList to set allowed distances?

Tags: algolia

I would like to be able to use the numericRefinementList to allow users to pick the distance from themselves an item can be? This would be using the IP geo-location feature or inputting the geo-location from browser if available.

- Less than 50km
- 50 - 100km
- 100 - 150km
- More than 150km

https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#numericrefinementlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not something you can do with the numericRefinementList but you can probably build a custom widget setting the `aroundRadius` depending on the link you've clicked on:

```
function radiusList(options) {
  if (!options.container) {
    throw new Error('radiusList: usage: radiusList({container, ...})');
  }
  var $container = $(options.container);
  if ($container.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('radiusList: cannot select \'' + options.container + '\'');
  }

  return {
    init: function(args) {
      // event delegation: set the aroundRadius of the underlying link
      $(document).on('click', '.radius-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        args.helper.setQueryParameter('aroundRadius', +$(this).data('radius'));
        args.helper.search();
      });
    },

    render: function(args) {
      // FIXME: display the list of radius links
      var html = '<ul>';
      html += '<li><a href="#" data-radius="100000" class="radius-link">&lt; 100km</a></li>';
      html += '</ul>';
      $container.html(html);
    }
  };
}
```

And then you use it with:

```
search.addWidget(radiusList({container: '#my-radius-list'}));
```